# Does the Drupal 7 DB contain sensitive info? Can I share a dump with 3rd party?

Tags: mysql, security, drupal

A guy I know asked me to give him the files and dump of my site to see how it works. Are there any stuff inside the Drupal 7 DB that are especially sensitive, like passwords?

Answer (score 1):

It does contain hashed passwords which could make it easier for someone to guess a user's password, as well as personal information such as users' email addresses. It would be best to provide it without the users table.

And that's just the base installation. If you add profile fields, nodes, or anything else with information you want to keep private (for example, if you use the Commerce module then you will have rules with the API access information for your payment provider) then those would be included in the database as well. Finding and removing all of these may not be easy.